# Git : how to organize two projects that have common code

Tags: git, tortoisegit, tortoisemerge

How two organize two projects that have common part of code ?

I have 2 projects that have common part of code, that is being
    changed from time to time. I use TortoiseGit.

For example

```
project 1 - master
project 2 - dev-branch.
```

As I understand when I make changes in dev-branch (changes in specific dev-branch code and in common with master code) and then merge master with dev-branch, master will get also specific dev-branch code.

How do I resolve this situation to get, for master, only master specific changes?

Comment: The Java and Android tags do not belong on this question.

Comment: I know, please see EDIT notion. But sometimes people from other areas can help too.

Comment: The fact that you know the tags are unrelated does not make it okay to add unrelated tags.  People will see the question anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You have to have an additional repository for the code you have in common. So in your case in total you'll have *super-project1*, *super-project2*, and a new *sub-project* repository.
2. For **any** of the files you want to be in the shared project, you must collect them into a special special sub directory (or tree) such that none of the super-project files are contained in the shared code directories.
3. After strict separation you can use Git's submodules or [git-subtree](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/subtree) ([Use Case of subtree](http://psionides.eu/2010/02/04/sharing-code-between-projects-with-git-subtree/), identical to yours)

Answer (score 1):

you could use [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) for this

--edit correcting link

Comment: Link is dead - a submodule tutorial for the command line: https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial - In TortoiseGit it's just right-click, Add Submodule.

Answer (score 1):

You can even have a git repo inside of a git repo, but you will end up 2 histories. I chose this option myself because I always change my inside git repo as a block since I want to update its unit tests whenever I update that repo.